# Отправка содержимого формы на почту

Tags: html, php, javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как написать htmi код, чтобы из форм на сайте приходило содержимое этих форм мне на e-mail(e-mail для примера возьмите test@test.ru). Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
   $data = "";
   foreach($_REQUEST['submit'] as $k=>$v){
      if($v != ""){
        $data .= $k." -- ".$v."\r\n";
      }
   }  
   if($data != ""){
      mail("test@test.ru","Site message",$data);
   }
}    
Как-то так если не стоит конкретной задачи
```